# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.1

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, jakarta-ee

when i launch my web application i get this error, i want to get some data from mongodb with spark and perform some spark-sql like the code:

i returned an empty list because i was testing but it shouldnt bug because of that the problem is when i fill the dataset with mongospark.

ive used the jars from spark folder so i dont think i have a problem with libs
and i ve already tried this in a java application and it works

```java
public List<temp> test(){
      List<temp> listtmp = new ArrayList<>();

      SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("spark://192.168.1.103:7077")
      .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
      .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/temperature.templog")
      .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/temperature.templog")
      .getOrCreate();


    // Create a JavaSparkContext using the SparkSession's SparkContext object
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

    /*Start Example: Read data from MongoDB************************/
    Dataset<Row> df = MongoSpark.load(jsc).toDF();
    /*End Example**************************************************/
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp");

    Dataset<Row> data = spark.sql("select * from temp");
    // Analyze data from MongoDB

    return listtmp;
    }
```

error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:370)
    at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MongoInferSchema$.apply(MongoInferSchema.scala:87)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark.toDF(MongoSpark.scala:587)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD.toDF(MongoRDD.scala:72)
    at com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD.toDF(JavaMongoRDD.scala:57)
    at model.SparkService.test(SparkService.java:48)
    at controller.FiltrageView.getGetresult(FiltrageView.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:732)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:792)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:1141)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:1120)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:445)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:376)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.5.1
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule.setupModule$(JacksonModule.scala:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:651)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 70 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are atleast using Spark 2.0, since you are using SparkSession

Jackson version that spark 2.0 supports is 2.6.5 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.0.2
Check for group ids beginning with `com.fasterxml.jackson`

Aside: The exception comes from `JacksonModule.scala` in `jackson-module-scala_2.11` dependency so Spark has a code level check for minimum jackson version, which i found very interesting !